# Javascript use single await in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, conditional-operator

I have a situation I want to use await in a ternary operator. I want to set a value to either a literal value or the resolve value of a promise, depending on a condition. Hopefully the code below will help describe what I want to do, but I am pretty sure it is not correct so consider it pseudo code.

```
const val = checkCondition ? "literal value" : await promiseGetValue();
```

Where promiseGetValue() returns a promise which resolves to a literal value. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: see this post: https://medium.com/@griffinmichl/async-await-with-ternary-operators-af19f374215

Comment: What exactly is the problem you need help with?  Your code looks valid to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a valid syntax, just for clarity u can surround the await promiseGetValue() with brackets. here is a demo of this syntax.

```js
const returnPromise = () => Promise.resolve('world')
const f = async () => {
   const x = true ? 'hello' : await returnPromise()
    const y = false ? 'hello' : await returnPromise()
    console.log(x,y)

}
f()
```

Answer (score 7):

The conditional operator expects *expressions* as operands, and `await value` is a valid expression.

So, if used inside an async function or in the top-level of a module that supports top-level `await` (where `await` is valid), your code is completely valid.

I can't say anything else about that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax,
However you should always use await inside async function.
You can return any value from function you are awaiting for(its not necessary to be promise, but it doesn't make sense to use await on function which is not returning promise)

```js
function promiseGetValue() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('any value')
        })
    })
}
const flag = false
async function main() {
    const val = flag ? "literal value" : await promiseGetValue();
    console.log(val)
}
main()
```

Comment: Answers with no explanatory text at all can always be improved and made more complete by adding text that explains a point you are attempting to make.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Also, when I try to run your code in the snippet, it doesn't run because `checkCondition` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [ehab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121608/1729441): The way you wrote it is perfectly fine, but you can also do it like this:

```js
const returnPromise = () => Promise.resolve("world");
const f = async () => {
  const x = await (true ? returnPromise() : returnPromise());
  console.log(x);
};
f();
```

That is to say, prepend the entire ternary expression, surrounded by parentheses, with `await`. Without the parentheses you would just `await true`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `await` with ternary operator is valid as long as the function with `async` keyword.

```js
  function promiseFunc() {
      return Promise.resolve({ some: 'data' });
    }
    
    async function myFunc(condition) {
      return condition ? await promiseFunc() : null;
    }
    
    (async () => {
      console.log(await myFunc(true))   // { some: 'data' }
    })()
```